# Codeigniter Active Record multi-update

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I update multiple rows using active record?

My array

```
foreach($services as $service){

        $this->service_batch[]=array(
            'service_id'=>$service->service_id,
            'service_count'=>$service->service_count,
            'id_customer'=>$service->id_customer,
            'id_section'=>$service->id_section);
        }
```

When I update the table, I need define 2 parameters in the `WHERE` clause (id_customer AND id_section), but if I use `update_batch`, I can specify only one parameter. 
How can I set a few parameters in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Have  a look in this Q and A - 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426094/codeigniter-batch-update-with-multiple-where-conditions

Comment: Use multiple `where`? Like `$this->db->where('id_section', $id_section);` `$this->db->where('id_customer', $id_customer);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this from the [Code Igniter Documentation - See Update Batch](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update) :-

```
 $data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->where($this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

in your case data will be replaced by `$this->service_batch` and title by your desired column.

Comment: What if he needs the 2 where parameters from his $data array ? This only works for a given id ?

Comment: @lxark just add another `$this->db->where($this->db->where('id', $id); ` statement ...

Comment: This is not what I meant... In your way of doing, this only works for matching only one id. What if I need to match the title AND the id for each array in $data array ? Do you mean I actually need to add a where statement for each of them ??

Comment: seems you want to irritate me,i have given the documentation link with  the answer.Anyway you can pass an associative array to `where()` like `$array = array('name' => $name, 'title' => $title, 'status' => $status);

$this->db->where($array); `

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure of catching what you exactly needs, but i would do:

```
//controller

foreach($services as $service){

        $this->model->update(
          $service->service_id,
          array(
            'service_count'=>$service->service_count,
            'id_customer'=>$service->id_customer,
            'id_section'=>$service->id_section
          ));
        }

//model


 function update($id,$data){

    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    return  $this->db->update('my_table',$data);

}
```