# Updating multiple records in database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Am trying to update multiple records in the database but my case I have a column total, which I want to update to different values. I haven't tried much here but hope I could get a clue on how to go about this.

**My controller**

```php
public function update_record()
{
    $id = ["19821", "19923", "19966", "19967"];
    $total = ["8", "118", "90", "100"];

    if ($this->some_model->batch_data('records', $total, $id) == true) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

}
```

**The Model**

```php
public function batch_data($table, $data, $where)
{
    $this->db->where_in('id',$where); 
    $this->db->set('total',$data); 
    $this->db->update($table);
    return true;
}
```

I have not tested this yet but currently looking for a more and efficient way of doing this.

Comment: you have to use loop to update one by one record with specific id, as per this code all the match record update with total array.

Comment: yea, i thought as much. but is there any other possible way to do this without looping through them one at a time?

Comment: you can use `$this->db->update_batch()`

Comment: @M.Hemant You can't add multiple where clauses to update_batch(). It only accepts a string as the third parameter for the where clause so I'm sure there's no way to do this the way the method is currently written. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426094/codeigniter-batch-update-with-multiple-where-conditions

Comment: great, would give a try

Comment: @courage In any case it will be loop because DB can't do it by one query

Comment: @splash58. you absolutely right, despite not running this line yet, i feel its absolutely wrong to update data in such a way.

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you want to do. i'm guessing, atleast it is the only way this makes sense, you want to update id 19821 to total 8 and 19923 to 118 .etc.?? (wherein won't work if this is the case) if so, then either a loop with single calls to the db wrapped in a transaction or update batch where the keys from the first array and values of the second array are combined will work, either way you'll have to do a loop.

Comment: @Alex you guessed it right, think looping through it would be the only reasonable solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still want to update multiple records using the `update_batch` method, you could first assign the `id` and `total` as key-value arrays, then use the `update_batch` method.

*Controller* :

```
public function update_record()
{
    $id = ["19821", "19923", "19966", "19967"];
    $total = ["8", "118", "90", "100"];
    $update_data = [];
    foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
        $update_data[] = [
            'id'    => $value,
            'total' => $total[$key]
        ];
    }

    if ($this->some_model->batch_data('records', $update_data) == true) {
        echo "yes";
    } else {
        echo "no";
    }

}
```

*Model* :

```
public function batch_data($table, $data)
{
    $this->db->update_batch($table, $data, 'id'); // this will set the id column as the condition field
    return true;
}
```

*Output* :

```
// preview query output : 
// UPDATE `records`
// SET
// `total` = 
// CASE 
//     WHEN `id` = '19821' THEN 8 
//     WHEN `id` = '19923' THEN 118 
//     WHEN `id` = '19966' THEN 90 
//     WHEN `id` = '19967' THEN 100 
//     ELSE `total`
// END 
// WHERE `id` IN ('19821', '19923', '19966', '19967')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Only for `single where condition`

Controller:

```
public function update_record()
    {
        $tableName = "records";
        $id = ["19821", "19923", "19966", "19967"];
        $total = ["8", "118", "90", "100"];
        $update_data = [];
        foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
            $update_data[] = [
                'id'    => $value,
                'total' => $total[$key]
            ];
        }
        $whereKey = 'id';
        $this->$this->some_model->batch_data($tableName, $updateData, $whereKey);
    }
```

Model:

```
public function batch_data($tableName, $updateData, $whereKey)
    {
        $this->db->update_batch($tableName, $updateData, $whereKey);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment. This is a method that combines the array in to key/value pairs and updates them 1x1 wrapped in a transaction (so if one query fails nothing changes).

This is the method I would personally use as I don't like `update_batch`s internal workings (cases).

```
$id = ["19821", "19923", "19966", "19967"];
$total = ["8", "118", "90", "100"];

$combined = array_combine($id, $total);

if (count($combined) > 0) {

    $this->db->trans_start();

    foreach ($combined as $id => $total) {

        $this->db->set('total', $total);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->update('sometable');

    }

    $this->db->trans_complete();

    return $this->db->trans_status();

}

return true;
```