# Problem in updating multiple row with multiple condition in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to make a multiple-row update in Codeigniter. I am getting an error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
One or more rows submitted for batch updating is missing the specified index.
```

I think the problem is within the model. I am putting the model function below please help me fix what I am doing wrong.

```
public function updateContacts($client_id){

    $data = array(
              array('address' => 'My address' ,
                    'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
                    ),
              array('address' => 'Another address' ,
                    'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
                   )
     );
    $multipleWhere = ['tbl_contact.owner_id' => $client_id, 'tbl_contact.owner_type' => '3'];
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_contact', $data, $multipleWhere);
}
```

Comment: can you show $data array/object please, but actually I don't think you can send an array as third parameter, check: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::update_batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter should be the key as per the official document, not the where condition

```
The first parameter will contain the table name, the second is an associative array of values, the third parameter is the where key.
```

But try as below

```
   $data = array(
              array('address' => 'My address' ,
                    'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
                    ),
              array('address' => 'Another address' ,
                    'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
                   )
     );

    $this->db->where('owner_id',$client_id);
    $this->db->update_batch('tbl_contact', $data, 'owner_type');
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I have tried this `$this->db->update_batch('tbl_contact', $data, 'key');`. But looks like it updates all the row's columns with the value of the column I am trying to update. For example, there are 12 rows in total. I am fetching 6 rows where the key = 3. And I want to change one row from 6 and insert the rest of the 5 rows as they are. But those 5 rows also update with the same value of that one row I am trying to change. I hope I am able to make you understand. The situation is a bit complicated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426094/codeigniter-batch-update-with-multiple-where-conditions

Comment: Please try as below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37750824/10240438